# I updated the android SDK from version 30 to 33 and my app (Ionic) no longer runs

Tags: android, xml, ionic-framework

i am trying to run my ionic app on android however google is now asking me to update the sdk i have which is version 30 to a higher version and this is version 33.
i try to update but i get this error

```
Error: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

this is my variables.gradle

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 33
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.1'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion    = '3.3.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
}
```

and this is my build.gradle file

```
build.gradle :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pegaso.frontera"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.pegaso.frontera']
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
AndroidManifest :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pegaso.frontera">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.pegaso.frontera.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
```

what am I doing wrong? sorry if I broke any rules

this is my previous variables.gradle

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.1'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion    = '3.3.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
}
```

ionic version 5

Comment: Manifest tag is not closed at bottom of file.